# vertically interrupted curly brace (or other bracket)

Tags: tables, brackets

In a LaTeX table, I'd like to add a curly brace of which only the top part is shown. The table then will contain lines with three vertical dots for lines not written out (`$\vdots$`). So the challenge is to typeset the top part of the curly brace (with the bottom "closing" part cut off) and possibly also to bottom "closing" part with the top part removed. I could then add these to separate table lines.

Can this be achieved?

I have tried a (clumsy) sketch of the top part... hope this conceives the idea...

[image]

Comment: The `abraces` package can create a customized *horizontal* brace including dashed lines, etc. You could probably put that in a box and rotate it through 90 degrees - see the `graphicx` package. I'm too busy to put all the details together right now, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bracket parts are available in the font, I put the font table on page 1 of the example so you can find other bits, but with a bit of manual tweaking for `}` you can get

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\xrbtop}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xrbmid}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"3D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xrbbot}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"41}
\newcommand\rbtop{\smash{\raisebox{5pt}{$\xrbtop$}}}
\newcommand\rbmid{\smash{\raisebox{12pt}{$\xrbmid$}}}
\newcommand\rbbot{\smash{\raisebox{15pt}{$\xrbbot$}}}
\newcommand\rbdots[1]{\smash{\raisebox{#1pt}{$\mkern6mu\vdots$}}}
\begin{document}

\xfonttable{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\[
  \begin{array}{cl}
A&\rbtop\\
B&\\
C&\rbdots{1}\\
D&\rbmid\\
E&\rbdots{-8}\\
F&\\
G&\rbbot\\    
\end{array}
=X
\]
\end{document}
```